# How do academics come up with new ideas all the time?

Tags: publications, research-process, productivity

I don't quite understand. How can some academics after hundreds of years of research on, say, Plato, still come up with novel, publishable interpretations, ideas, readings, solutions to these texts?

Plato is a good example for this, I think. But i am generally confused how this works, and how people can still come up with new ideas all the time.

Doesn't it get more difficult after some time?

Comment: [How to come up with research ideas?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5853/how-to-come-up-with-research-ideas)

Comment: thank you! this is interesting. However, here I am asking something more general, I am wondering how this work *in general*, I am not looking for practical advice, I am just baffled how this is possible at all. Esp. in fields like Classics.

Comment: Perhaps looking at how academics do it will help you understand how it is possible.

Comment: sure! its highly relevant, and I am reading it right now. but so far the advice is very 'practical': be curious, be challenged, know your field - it's interesting, but not what I try to get at. i just don't understand how a field can not be depleted after some time.

Comment: maybe my question here is too broad or difficult to answer.

Comment: Sayings like "the deeper you look at anything, the more holes you find," etc. are *true*. The deeper you understand a variety of fields, the more synergy you can find, the more novel applications of concepts from Field A can be pushed into Field B. Your question isn't too broad or difficult to answer; you're simply questioning how civilization and technological/scientific/social development occur.

Comment: Adding on to @JoMcBride, this question has too many good answers in which no single answer can be correct as to be accepted as final.

Comment: Actually that part is pretty easy, especially in the humanities. If you read the papers/books of leaders in a field you'll naturally develop your own ideas and theories.

Comment: It's actually not that difficult in the sciences (philosophy I can't speak to). Imagine all of knowledge as a sphere. Scientists operate at the edge of the sphere, constantly hacking away to make it larger. The steps are small. Few if any research papers conclude with a definitive answer; rather they suggest (and encourage) more work, often plainly spelled out in the conclusions.