# After finding the topic how to discover research problem in Mathematics

Tags: mathematics, research-topic

I am at an early stage of my research in Mathematics. Recently I have found some papers related to my broad interest that I think I will be able to work on.

However I am clueless how to find the research problem or in which direction I should proceed . Is it okay to mail the author asking for research problem or at least asking for the direction in which I can proceed. More generally how should I approach to some experts via email asking for such stuffs.

Comment: Where is your supervisor?  You can email authors but I doubt they will reply.  I for example will keep all 'good' problems for myself and my students.

Comment: i am discussing it with my supervisor but this field is also new to my supervisor

Comment: this is the reason why I am looking for a second opinion

Comment: It's probably better to find research problems on your own. See [How to come up with research ideas?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/5853/17254) for ideas on how to do so.

Comment: It is totally fine and common to consult with your adviser in this situation. Tell him/her about the paper and ask for an advice on how to proceed further.